# Fix lagging jQuery UI Slider update values

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, uislider

http://jsfiddle.net/emcniece/7Zj7M/2/

I can't figure out why the slider `slide: function()` only seems to update to the previous position. The sliders and labels start at the correct locations (1 and 3), but they don't update the labels on the first move... then for every move after that, they return the previous location value. For example:

1. Move min slide handle (value 1) to the right - labels don't update
2. Move min slide handle (now should be value 2) to the left - label updates to "2", even though handle position should be "1"
3. Move min slide handle left, then right once more. Slide handle is now in the "1" position, but the label value is 0

I tried to follow the example at http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range - What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the handles' values haven't been changed yet when the 'slide' event occurs.  You're always logging the current values for each handle, not the "just-moved-the-slider-to" values.

According to the [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide), `ui.value` contains the value which the handle will have if you do not cancel the slide event.  And `ui.values` is an array containing the values for both handles (with the same caveat).  So, try this:

```
slide: function(e, u){
    $(this).parent().children('.label-min').text(u.values[0]);
    $(this).parent().children('.label-max').text(u.values[1]);
},
```